# imagemagick - run command on all files in folder and output results to their own sub-folders

Tags: command-line, imagemagick

I am on windows using this command to split a sprite sheet into multiples files (frames) -

```
magick convert images\1.png -crop 1024x1024 images\1.png
```

Which works fine, problem is that I need to do this to 5k+ sprite sheets and create a sub-folder for each set of frames. I tried searching for an answer and found out about `mogrify` but I'm unsure how to use it for my situation?

**EDIT:**
Input images are all named sequentially 1 to 5000. Output folder will be name respectively and output files will also be named in sequence 1-30.

Comment: You didn't say what OS you use, nor really explain how your input files are named and what the corresponding output files should be named.

Comment: Mogrify is intended to create one output image per each input image. So you will need to write a script loop over each input image and write all your output files from the crop to whatever output directory you want to place them.  P.S. In ImageMagick 7, use magick, not magick convert. Other tools such as identify and montage in IM 7 become magick identify and magick montage. Just not convert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured out how to do on a small batch of files. Haven't tested on the full set yet.

I ended up creating a .bat file and running a loop on my commands. With the use of the counter I was able to get the names to be numeric and sequentially.

```
@echo off 
set count=10
:loop
mkdir %count%
mkdir %count%\sequence-%count%
magick %count%.png -crop 1024x1024 %count%/sequence-%count%/%count%.png
set /a count=count-1 
if %count%==0 goto exitloop 
goto loop 
:exitloop 
pause
```